# Which is faster: image segmentation or line detection?

Tags: image-processing, algorithms, image-segmentation, edge-detection, real-time

Some papers use image segmentation techniques and others use edge detection. I need to know which one is faster.

*update:*

I need to do semantic segmentation for outdoor sense and the data is optical image and LiDAR. Other researchers use segmentation before doing feature detection but I expect that if I use line/edge detection, the technique will detect image features faster.

Before I start doing experiments I want to know which one is better because this will effect on next step, i.e. feature detect.

This application should work in real-time and I plan to use GPU for faster processing, such as CUDA.

Comment: Welcome to SP.SE! Your question is very, very general and not clear. You need to provide much more information: what sort of images are you using? What is the application that you need edge detection / segmentation for?  What have you tried? How fast do you need it?  Closing until we get some more details.

Comment: @peterK. I add all info you ask for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image segmentation is way harder and more complex than a local operation like edge detection. You may do things in parallel for edge detection as one does not interfere with the other. Global segmentation can't allow this.